# Error in A Simple D3 Line chart with Legend and Tooltips for D3v 3.5.13

Tags: javascript, d3.js

It is a long shot, but I don't suppose anyone would know how to fix the error in Chrome:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined.

for [this stunning visualization](http://bl.ocks.org/bobmonteverde/2070123). I have narrowed the error down to line 7486 (When uniminifying the code and opening in Sublime Text 2). In FireFox the error is:

> TypeError: e[a] is undefined

.

```
Il.transition = function() {
        for (var n, t, e, r, u = this.id, i = ++Yl, a = this.namespace, o = [], l = 0, c = this.length; c > l; l++) {
            o.push(n = []);
            for (var t = this[l], s = 0, f = t.length; f > s; s++)(e = t[s]) && (r = e[a][u], Qi(e, s, a, i, {
                time: r.time,
                ease: r.ease,
                delay: r.delay + r.duration,
                duration: r.duration
            })), n.push(e)
        }
        return Wi(o, a, i)
```

I would love to use it in a project of mine, but it is generating the above error upon hovering over the top legend items (Cosine2 Wave etc).

It is currently using [D3v2.??](http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js). Upon using this version, the visualization works flawlessly, but begins to error out on the newer versions of D3.

Any assistance would be great, I have been trying to address it to no avail, and frankly, I am not that good at D3 or JavaScript in general to be able to figure this out in a timely manner.

Thank so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem relates to the use of transitions.  There are four places where the `chart` function is called with a selection that has been returned from `.transition()`, and that appears not to work.

Three of the four changes are in lines 63, 69 and 74 of `d3linewithlegend.js`.  Each of these three lines reads as follows:

```
        selection.transition().call(chart)
```

Replace each line with

```
        selection.call(chart).transition()
```

Finally, in the `index.html` file, replace

```
  svg.transition().duration(500)
      .attr('width', width(margin))
      .attr('height', height(margin))
      .call(chart);
```

with

```
  svg.call(chart).transition().duration(500)
      .attr('width', width(margin))
      .attr('height', height(margin))
```

After making this change, hovering over the legend worked for me, in Chrome, Firefox and Edge.

Transitions were overhauled in D3 version 3.0, so it's perhaps not a surprise that D3 v2 code involving them doesn't work in D3 v3.  I can't say I understand them well enough to know exactly where the problem is, but I did observe that if enter the following line in the console

```
d3.select("body").transition().transition()
```

then D3 throws the same exception that I got when I tried to view the visualization you linked to.  This led me to avoid a situation where `transition()` was being called on a selection returned by a call to `transition()`.

Comment: Not a bad guess, but the tool tips work in both version. The issue is with the transition being carried out on <g class="legend" ...>. Or am I misunderstanding you? Also, where did you see that line "... transitions().transition()"?

Comment: @Mr.Concolato: sorry, it seems I've been a bit unclear.  The change I made should fix the legend, I just clumsily wrote 'tooltips'.  I've fixed that now.  The line that ends `.transition().transition()` isn't in the code anywhere: I just typed it in in the console and got the same error message.  It was what I was doing to try to figure out what was going on and to provide some kind of explanation as to why I suggested the fix above.

Comment: No worries Luke. I tried what you recommended and it did not work for the legend elements. They still return the error listed above. Did you get your code to work?

Comment: @Mr.Concolato: apologies, I was trying a few things out last night and managed to omit from my answer one of the things that was necessary.  There's another change that needs to be made, similar to the existing three.  I've edited my answer to include it.  I've tested it again and it really should work this time.  Sorry!

Comment: I have made the above changes, and there is an improvement, but now the error is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined. I still cannot hide the lines. Also, I noticed that with your code changes, the chart still works perfectly with D3v2. What am I missing?

Comment: @Mr.Concolato: I can't be sure.  I downloaded the original files from the link you provided and have double-checked that the only differences are the changes I suggested above and the replacement of D3 v2 with D3 v3.  The changes work for me: the graph lines embolden when I hover over the corresponding legend items, this effect reverses when I move the mouse away, and I can click the legend items to show/hide the lines.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101434/discussion-between-mr-concolato-and-luke-woodward).